# json.loads() with escaped characters python3

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, jsonparser

I have a data from kinesis stream and it has escape characters. When I try to convert that data in json format in python3 using json.loads it failes `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 22 (char 21)`

Sample event is below,

```
event='{"logEvents":[{"message":"{\"objectType\":\"HANDLER_OBJECT\",\"event\":{\"source\":\"Test\",\"action\":\"PLAY\",\"type\":\"SH\",\"timestamp\":1576223901848,\"key\":\"A|12|B|12|C|123|R|1|SH\",\"value\":\"{\\\"type\\\":\\\"THIS_IS_TEST\\\",\\\"objectId\\\":\\\"123ae43fd46fg\\\",\\\"containerId\\\":\\\"122122321212343212\\\",\\\"testId\\\":\\\"0\\\",\\\"testContainerId\\\":\\\"122122321212343212\\\",\\\"version\\\":4,\\\"reattemptVersion\\\":1,\\\"pId\\\":\\\"122122321212343212|123ae43fd46fg\\\",\\\"active\\\":true,\\\"sOn\\\":1576222508,\\\"cOn\\\":0,\\\"time\\\":1576226109,\\\"hIds\\\":[],\\\"mScore\\\":4000,\\\"cy\\\":null,\\\"ceOn\\\":null,\\\"rr\\\":[],\\\"cS\\\":null}\"}}"}]}'
```

code I tried,

```
json.loads(event)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 380, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting , delimiter: line 1 column 29 (char 28)
```

I know converting `\` with `\\` will solve this issue but sometime special characters can also come and thus cannot be just handled using replace.

I have also checked simialar SO issues and solutions but none of them worked. I have tried, `json.loads(event.encode('unicode_escape'))` and `json.loads(r'{}'.format(event))` but none worked. Can anybody provide a solution or better json parsing module/library in python3?

Comment: please show output of `print(events)`

Comment: what is `event`?  Note, the following key in your JSON: `"{\"objectType\":\"HANDLER_OBJECT\",\"event\"...` looks like someone serialized a valid JSON string as part of a JSON object... why would you do that?

Comment: @AlexandrShurigin event is the json string i earlier showed in question, I have updated the question now.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga This is structure of event string I get from kinesis and I am trying to convert it back to json.

Comment: Where from it the data coming? I am sure it is not JSON. It is some sort of mix. But data you added for `event=` is not correct with escaping

Comment: RIGHT! There was missing `r'..'`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where from is the data coming, but! But here we are!

```
import json

event = r'{"logEvents":[{"message":"{\"objectType\":\"HANDLER_OBJECT\",\"event\":{\"source\":\"Test\",\"action\":\"PLAY\",\"type\":\"SH\",\"timestamp\":1576223901848,\"key\":\"A|12|B|12|C|123|R|1|SH\",\"value\":\"{\\\"type\\\":\\\"THIS_IS_TEST\\\",\\\"objectId\\\":\\\"123ae43fd46fg\\\",\\\"containerId\\\":\\\"122122321212343212\\\",\\\"testId\\\":\\\"0\\\",\\\"testContainerId\\\":\\\"122122321212343212\\\",\\\"version\\\":4,\\\"reattemptVersion\\\":1,\\\"pId\\\":\\\"122122321212343212|123ae43fd46fg\\\",\\\"active\\\":true,\\\"sOn\\\":1576222508,\\\"cOn\\\":0,\\\"time\\\":1576226109,\\\"hIds\\\":[],\\\"mScore\\\":4000,\\\"cy\\\":null,\\\"ceOn\\\":null,\\\"rr\\\":[],\\\"cS\\\":null}\"}}"}]}'


def to_python(event):
    event = eval(event)

    for e in event['logEvents']:
        e['message'] = json.loads(e['message'])
        e['message']['event']['value'] = json.loads(e['message']['event']['value'])

    return event


from pprint import pprint

pprint(to_python(event))
```

Output

```
{'logEvents': [{'message': {'event': {'action': 'PLAY',
                                      'key': 'A|12|B|12|C|123|R|1|SH',
                                      'source': 'Test',
                                      'timestamp': 1576223901848,
                                      'type': 'SH',
                                      'value': {'active': True,
                                                'cOn': 0,
                                                'cS': None,
                                                'ceOn': None,
                                                'containerId': '122122321212343212',
                                                'cy': None,
                                                'hIds': [],
                                                'mScore': 4000,
                                                'objectId': '123ae43fd46fg',
                                                'pId': '122122321212343212|123ae43fd46fg',
                                                'reattemptVersion': 1,
                                                'rr': [],
                                                'sOn': 1576222508,
                                                'testContainerId': '122122321212343212',
                                                'testId': '0',
                                                'time': 1576226109,
                                                'type': 'THIS_IS_TEST',
                                                'version': 4}},
                            'objectType': 'HANDLER_OBJECT'}}]}
```